# Parameter is not valid Exception while displaying image from database

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I know this question has been asked many times, but my problem is not being solved.

I inserted image to database and data type of my field is image. But I am trying to display the image in picture box this exception occurs.

> Parameter is not valid.

Here is my code:

```
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {                
            byte[] Img = (byte[])dr["imgImage"];
            MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(Img);
            MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            //System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
            //System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image)converter.ConvertFrom(Img);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(MS);
        }
```

Comment: You cannot use [`Image.FromStream( ms )`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: I used but it's not working too.

Answer (score 0):

i guess it works.

```
PCT.Image= Image.FromStream(ms);
```

is that works? 
edit1:

```
    ////sql connection codes here
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();    
    while (dr.Read())    
    {    
    byte[] picture = (byte[])dr[0];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(picture, 0, picture.Length); 
    ms.Write(picture, 0, picture.Length);    
    RegPicture = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
    pictureBox1.Image = RegPicture;    
    }
    ////sql connection codes here
```

Comment: Still the same :(

Comment: What is `RegPicture` ?

Comment: i didn't write, sorry. it is a Image object.

Comment: i mean --> Image RegPicture = null;  //write above

Comment: Still the same problem friend :(

Comment: i can not understand :( it should be ok. still the same?